# Which test should I use to compare difference in expected and observed values?

Tags: variance

I have river health data in the form of three biotic indices - the BMWP, NTAXA, and ASPT scores. I have also got a set of expected scores for these metrics at each of the 16 sampling points, which are based on the RIVPACS/RICT database. This calculates a score based on information collected at the site. The 16 samples are from two sections of a river; restored and control.

I want to see if the difference between the observed and expected values is dependent on whether the sample was taken from the restored stretch or the control stretch. Basically, I want to see if the restored stretch has got any closer to being 'ideal' (the standard of which is the expected value) since being restored.

Which test should I use? I'm quite stuck!

Thanks in advance,

JH

Comment: On what units are these "scores" measured?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear to start with. They are all based on abundancy. The BMWP metric is calculated per sample by assigning values to taxa based on their resistance to pollution and other factors. If the relevant taxa is present in the sample, then the score is added to the overall sum. The NTAXA is just the number of taxa present in the sample, and the ASPT is the average score per taxon - BMWP/NTAXA.

Comment: is resistance to pollution measured as a proportion, as an LC50 concentration, or some completely subjective measure?

Comment: It's measured as a score out of 10 - completely subjective, and I'm not entirely sure how they are worked out. The taxa are effectively ranked by their ability to cope with the stresses that the system measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a simple and direct application of the t-test. A caution about observed/expected: such specifications are usually an offhand way of specifying a one sample test. The introduced limitation is that you must *trust* the expected values are right, and the whole thing is invalid otherwise. You've technically done a better design: this is a two sample test. Rather than telling us what "expected" values are, you sampled from a control. Conduct a two sample test for an ordinal difference in the 0-10 scale of resilience and use corrections for uneven variance.

Comment: Thank you very much Adam, I had initially done a t-test but the more I looked into it the less confident I got. By the way, this isn't the only part of my analysis - it's almost a last-minute idea that I thought I may as well include. Thanks again for your help!